# jquery ajax - global settings. Is it possible to know what event/element trigger the ajax call?

Tags: ajax, jquery

This is easy enough to work around, but it would be nice if it was wrapped up in the global ajax setup

When I run an ajax call, I'd like to know which element/event trigger the ajax call in the beforeSend option.

Is there a concise way of doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `beforeSend` callback takes two arguments: the `XMLHTTPRequest` instance and the settings used by the current AJAX call.

Therefore, if you pass the triggering element and event in the `context` option, they will be available to `beforeSend` even if you define it in the global setup:

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        var element = settings.context.element;
        var event = settings.context.event;

        // Do something with 'element' and 'event'...
    }
});

$("selector").click(function(e) {
    $.ajax("url", {
        // your settings,
        context: {
            element: this,
            event: e
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Start Here

[Global Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

These methods register handlers to be called when certain events, such as initialization or completion, take place for any AJAX request on the page. The global events are fired on each AJAX request if the global property in `jQuery.ajaxSetup()` is true, which it is by default. Note: Global events are never fired for cross-domain script or JSONP requests, regardless of the value of global.

```
.ajaxComplete()  // initialize in for all ajax request and set event in jQuery.ajaxSetup()
```

[.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) - Register a handler to be called when Ajax requests complete. This is an Ajax Event.