# How to access click handler in $.ajaxSetup()

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    async:false,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(){
        $(this).next('.ajaxLoader').show();
        console.log($(this));
    },
    complete: function(){
        $(this).next('.ajaxLoader').hide();
    }
});
```

But the problem is that `$(this)` points to 'body' in the beforeSend and it points to the jQuery object in the complete function. I need both function's $(this) to reference the click handler that is currently being used.

EDIT: correct answer found!

[jquery ajax - global settings. Is it possible to know what event/element trigger the ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812140/jquery-ajax-global-settings-is-it-possible-to-know-what-event-element-trigger)

Comment: @FelixKling this is very different.

Comment: @FelixKling. How do you remember?

Comment: Ah.... sorry. I see now that you use `ajaxSetup`. So it is indeed different, nevermind.

Comment: @gordon: Search and compare names ;) Anyways, it is not the same situation...

Comment: @FelixKling Yup! Didnt work in this case...

Comment: So I assume you already set `context: this` in your actual call. That's why it works in `complete` but not in `beforeSend`?

Comment: @gdoron: Deleted my previous comments...

Comment: @FelixKling. So your memory isn't so well after one year, isn't it... **=)**

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery ajax - global settings. Is it possible to know what event/element trigger the ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812140/jquery-ajax-global-settings-is-it-possible-to-know-what-event-element-trigger) -- I actually found that one as well, but discarded it because I did not understand your question correctly and then I could not find it anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Updating the answer based on [jquery ajax - global settings. Is it possible to know what event/element trigger the ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812140/jquery-ajax-global-settings-is-it-possible-to-know-what-event-element-trigger)

```
var $this;
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    async:false,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings){
        $this = settings.context.element;
        $this.next('.ajaxLoader').show();
        console.log($this);
    },
    complete: function(){
        $this.next('.ajaxLoader').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: `this` needs to refer to the click event target, not the context in which ajax was setup.

Comment: Thanks dude for pointing this out..since the OP got the problem solved.. i have updated the answer based on given reference.