# Get Referenced Element in jQuery $.ajaxSetup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building a framework and I want to write some generic functions for buttons when they are clicked before and after an ajax call is made.

My problem is how do I reference to the actual element itself.

`$(this)` in this case references to the xhr I guess.

```
$.ajaxSetup({

    beforeSend : function(){
        $(this).css('cursor', 'wait');
        $(this).text('wait...');
    },

    error : function(){
        $(this).css('cursor', 'normal');
    }

});
```

Comment: What element is it your after?

Comment: `<a>` and some times `<button>`. The thing is I don't want to write beforeSend and error methods in each ajax call, and would like to rather have one generic method for all cases.

Comment: i just updated my answer, check it out...

Answer (score 0):

I found another question about this with an answer:

[jquery ajax - global settings. Is it possible to know what event/element trigger the ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812140/jquery-ajax-global-settings-is-it-possible-to-know-what-event-element-trigger)

Moreover the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) says:

> Note: Global callback functions should be set with their respective
>   global Ajax event handler methods—.ajaxStart(), .ajaxStop(),
>   .ajaxComplete(), .ajaxError(), .ajaxSuccess(), .ajaxSend()—rather than
>   within the options object for $.ajaxSetup().

**My old answer:**

> You sould bind an onclick listener on the buttons you want to take
>   ajax action on. In this case you can access the button with this:
>
> ```
> $(this).addClass('a');
> // ajax calls...
> ```
>
> example: http://jsfiddle.net/ichr/s6EUg/2/

Comment: Thanks, did I mention generic function for all buttons?