# Bootbox dialog.modal('hide') doesn't hide modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootbox

I have a problem with bootbox.js modals.
Being executed and waiting for response ready State changed to 3 and model will show 
But after the request is complete and ready state changed to 4  and `readystate 4` is printing in console.log but model doesn't hide.

```
    var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
    message: '<p class="text-center mb-0"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-cog"></i> Please wait while we do something...</p>',
    className: 'bounceInUp animated',
    closeButton: false,
    show: false
                                  });

// ready stat with jquery
var _orgAjax = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr;

jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function () {
    var xhr = _orgAjax();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

      console.log(xhr.readyState);

      var state = xhr.readyState;


      if (state == 3 ) {

      dialog.modal('show');
      console.log('readystate 3 ');

      }else if (state == 4) {

        dialog.modal('hide');
        console.log('readystate 4 ');

      };




    }
   return xhr;
};
```

Comment: if you use jquery why you not use $.ajax ??

Comment: i used it after this code

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in ajax request by options `beforeSend` and close it always when ajax is finished.

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend: function() {
    dialog.modal('show'); <------------------ HERE show before
  },
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
})
.always(function( msg ) {
    dialog.modal('show'); <----------------- HERE hide always on finish
 });
```

Also you can use [$.ajaxSetup](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) like [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812140/jquery-ajax-global-settings-is-it-possible-to-know-what-event-element-trigger) but **from documentation its use is not recommended**.

Comment: thanx for ur help ,, but after try ur code i get this error  -> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'  --> this . before .always function

Comment: @TarekRamadan ah ty redundant ; after done. Updated.